# Failed to connect to Azure SQL Database using ODBC Driver 17 with Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, odbc

I was trying to connect the Azure Container Instance to my Azure SQL Database using Azure Active DIrectory User Managed Identity. But I can't establish a connection using ODBC Driver 17.

###### Error Message:

```
[S1T00][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

[FA004][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user '' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryMSI').
Error code 0xA190; state 41360
Required metadata header not specified or not correct
Required metadata header not specified or not correct
Required metadata header not specified or not correct
Required metadata header not specified or not correct

[CE275][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error requesting access token, HTTP status 400, expected 200

[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. 

[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response
```

###### Configuration Details:

- The ODBC driver used in the docker image has a version of 17.10.5.1-1,
- The identity has been assigned to the container instanc and is set as a external user of the database in table [sys.database_principals]
- The identity is set as a contributor to the database.
- Network connectivity from the Azure Container Instance to the SQL Server has been checked and confirmed.
- The DNS configuration according to [Using Azure Active Directory with the ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
[dns-name]
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server=<server-name>
Database=<database-name>
UID=<object id of the assigned identity>
Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi
Encrypt=yes
```

Could anyone help identify the cause of these errors or suggest troubleshooting steps? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error You are not able to login in SQL server with Managed Identity

1. Enable managed identity on Azure Container Instance and assign appropriate role to it to access SQL server.
   [image]
2. Then Add this managed identity to your SQL server's Microsoft Entra ID and create corresponding user to it for login with

```sql
CREATE  USER [<identity-name>] FROM  EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

3. Then use below code to authenticate.

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import pyodbc, struct

credential = DefaultAzureCredential() # system-assigned identity
credential = DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id='<client-id-of-user-assigned-identity>') # user-assigned identity

# Get token for Azure SQL Database and convert to UTF-16-LE for SQL Server driver
token = credential.get_token("https://database.windows.net/.default").token.encode("UTF-16-LE")
token_struct = struct.pack(f'<I{len(token)}s', len(token), token)

# Connect with the token
SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256
connString = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER=<server-name>.database.windows.net;DATABASE=<database-name>"
conn = pyodbc.connect(connString, attrs_before={SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN: token_struct})
```

Comment: Hi Pratik, Thank you for answering my question! The application I run in the container relies on the DSN to establish the connection. Is there any way I could authenticate using the DSN set in ODBC.ini?

Comment: Try servername as `Server = tcp:severname,1433` In your DSN and then authenticate?